# How can i solve RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-test

Each time a page was built, we used onCalendarCreated to import the totoList for the current date.

However, RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 error occurs.

I think it's a problem with ListViewBuilder, how can I solve this error?

Here is my full error code

```
  RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

  When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
  #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:177:60)
  #1      _TimeTableState.todoCard (package:take_a_note_project/calender_view/month_table.dart:155:27)
  #2      _TimeTableState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:take_a_note_project/calender_view/month_table.dart:113:40)
  #3      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:449:22)
  #4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1130:28)
```

// get todoList code

```
onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
              setState(() {
                todoListHandler.selectedEvents = events;
                todoListHandler.getDone(controller.selectedDay);
              });
            },
onCalendarCreated: (DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
              todoListHandler.doneTodo.isEmpty
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : todoListHandler.getDone(controller.selectedDay);
            },
```

//Listbuilder code

```
Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: todoListHandler.doneTodo.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return GestureDetector(
                              child: todoCard(context,
                                  todoListHandler.doneTodo,
                                  index
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                      ),
                    )
```

//todoCard code

```
Widget todoCard(BuildContext context, todoItem, int index) {
  Color color = Colors.white38;
  Color titleColor = Colors.white;
  String toDo = todoItem[index].todo;
  String startTime = todoItem[index].startTime;
  String endTime = todoItem[index].endTime;

  return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      color: color,
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled_solid, color: Colors.greenAccent, size: 45,),
        title: Text(
            (startTime != null) ? "$startTime ~ $endTime" : "- ~ -"
            ,style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 20, color: titleColor)),
        subtitle: Text(toDo, style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white70
        ),),
      )
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether todoItem is empty or not?

Comment: Yes.. after that error code the todo Item shows well..

Answer (score -3):

I am getting the same erorr.. may be this is because the Array is overflowing with too much data.

Comment: Hi! Since you are new, I would like to mention that what you contributed would better be suited as a comment than an actual answer, since you are speculating, which is not a solution. I am just mentioning this in case you are wondering where the downvotes are coming from.